# Memory and swap space are full

Tags: 22.04, ram, crash, swap

My Ubuntu keeps crashing 3-4 times a week, and apps like VSCode crash twice a day.

`htop` RAM and swap usage:

[image: htop RAM and swap usage]

I have 16GB RAM and 32GB swap running Ubuntu 22.04 and all of it is full most of the time. (other stats: CPU: 16-25%, temperature: 49-55 degrees)
At the time of screenshot running: 30+ tabs and 3-4 dev console on Chrome, 3-4 VSCode windows, 3-4 LibreOffice Calc, Microsoft Teams and 2 Terminator windows, And Vagrant with homestead including about 12-15 websites (2GB RAM allocated).

Is this expected usage or is there something wrong with my system?

Full `htop` :

[image: Full htop screenshot]

Comment: You're using htop. Where does htop show that the resources are being used?

Comment: There is something wrong with the system. All those windows should not use more than 10GB RAM.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of htop with memory sorting selected?

Comment: @france1 Updated with full screenshot of htop

Comment: Could you include an `htop` screenshot where you hid userthreads (uncheck `Show userland process threads` under Display Options), and sort by memory usage, descending? *(the userthreads really clutter up the display)*